# what is the first abstract operation that takes place in ecma262 in order to start the global execution context?

Tags: javascript

what is the first abstract operation that takes place in ecma262 in order to start the global execution context ?

does it [ScriptEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) or maybe [InitializeHostDefinedRealm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) or none of these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitializeHostDefinedRealm` seems to be the most promising candidate.

Notice that for `ScriptEvaluation`, you need a *script record*, so you'd usually call `ParseScript` first. But for that, you need a *realm*, which indeed would be created via `InitializeHostDefinedRealm`.

Of course, a host is free not to use any of these in theory. It might restore the entire state of the global execution context from a static image on disk, and begin execution in the middle of whatever was running when the state was frozen.